# Can you define a stochastic process via its marginals?

Tags: stochastic-processes

If you are given a finite fumber of r.v. say $X_1...X_n$ and you know say the conditional distribution of each one given the preceding ones (i.e with smaller index) values , and you also know the marginal say $X_1$ then there is a unique measure satisfying these conditions

I am curious wether this generalizes to an infinite family indexed say by $R$. The marginal distributions could be expressed given the sigma algebra generated by the preceding ones.

Comment: Hi: based on your question, I think you might be referring to the kolmogorov extension theorem. check that out because, if I'm correct, then you'll find a lot about it is discussed on this list in past threads.

Comment: That theorem only considers the special case that the marginals are independants, although it can "probably" be used as a lemma for this problem.